# Angularjs math on bound scope objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to run basic math functions on bound scope objects in my controller. The view is a series of sliders that will need to react based on the user input of a few different sliders. I can't seem to get the values to live update on the front end.

This is my 'calculations' for those values.

```
$scope.mainSlide = {
    assets: ($scope.slide1.assets * $scope.slide2.assets / .1),
    roa: ($scope.slide1.roa * $scope.slide2.roa / .1)
};
```

Im a bit confused why the computed values aren't being bound on the front end.

Any help, or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Phill trying to get mainSlide to update on the view as the values in slide1.assets... etc change. It's supposed to compute the values, and output to a different range slider, kind of like a live graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For computed properties on the `$scope`, you can use `$scope.$watch` to recompute when a value changes and set the new value (for example watch slide1 and slide2, set value of mainslide when they change). You can also set mainSlide's computed values to be functions and they will be updated automatically:

In your case:

```
$scope.mainSlide = {
  assets: function() { return ($scope.slide1.assets * $scope.slide2.assets / .1);},
  roa: function() { return ($scope.slide1.roa * $scope.slide2.roa / .1);}
};
```

To use them in your view:

```
Assets: {{mainSlide.assets()}}
Roa: {{mainSlide.roa()}}
```

Example Plunker for function method: http://plnkr.co/edit/tFiZ5z?p=preview

Example Plunker for $watch method: http://plnkr.co/edit/5iASgJ?p=preview

Comment: This worked great. However (something i didn't include), How can I apply this to an ng-model attribute on my view?

Comment: In that case I'd just use the $watch method. Updated answer to add an example Plunker.

Comment: thanks so much, worked like a charm. I guess i need to learn more about the $watch method.

Comment: any chance you'd be able to include a way to bind the other way so that the mainSlide.assets and mainSlide.roa numbers link up with the other values? I started another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324942/angularjs-watch-with-2-way-binding